# Как занести id пользователя в переменную js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

так получить *id* пользователя в php

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user']['userID'];
```

Как получить *id* пользователя в js?

```
var ratedIndex = -1, uID = document.cookie.match('/PHPSESSID/');
```

Comment: Если у Вас сервер формирует страницу, то почему бы не использовать её для передачи необходимых параметров в JS используя сериализацию JSON? <script>var userId = <?php echo $_SESSION['user']['userID'];?></script>

Comment: @XelaNimed, спасибо большое, помогло